# pass an Object from Service to Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-service

I want to pass a Object from a Service to Activity. Should i use Intents and a Object with Parcelable interface?! if so, do i have a BroadcastReceiver in Activity?

```
//in the service class        
qId = new QueueIdentifier(sensorUnits.get(sensorUnits.size()-1).getDeviceDescriptor(),
                sensorUnits.get(sensorUnits.size()-1).getMasterID());
        //send qId to DeviceListFragment --> DeviceListFragment is already exist
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DeviceListFragment.class);
        intent.putExtra("qid",qId);
```

Comment: It would depend on your situation, is the service in the same process? are you passing it due to some event occurring? or is it just a return value through a binder interface?

Comment: Wooo.. wait, you can not start fragment with an `Intent`. I'll rephrase.. even you can not "start" `fragment`.

Comment: i use a AsyncTask in a Fragment to call a method from a class which extends Service.